# How to remove the user from particular role in angular?

Tags: angular

component.ts[In this code, I would like to remove the user from the particular role...
 but it is not removed from the role. API is working fine but in angular, it is not removing...
 what is wrong with this? could you please send some solutions if you can able to trace it out??]

```
 removeUsers(master, name) {
    console.log(master)

    if (master.is_master === true) {

          this.payload = {
            "companyusers_id":master.company_user_id.id,
            "role_id" : master.role_id
           }
           console.log(this.payload)

    }
    else {

         this.payload ={
            "companyusers_id":master.company_user_id.id,
            "role_id" : master.role_task_id.role_id,
            "task_id" : master.role_task_id.id
          }
          console.log(this.payload)

        }
        this.removeUserRoles(this.payload);

  }
removeUserRoles(payload){
      this.store.dispatch(new RemoveUserRoles(payload))
      this.store.pipe(select(getRemoveUserRolesSuccess)).subscribe((result:any)=>{

            console.log(result);
            alert("User Removed Successfully")


      })
    this.store.pipe(select(getRemoveUserRolesError)).subscribe((result:any)=>{
      if(!!result){
        console.log(result)
        }
```

html(In this code, I would like to remove the user from the particular role...
 but it is not removed from the role. API is working fine but in angular, it is not removing...
 what is wrong with this? could you please send some solutions if you can able to trace it out??)

```
 <div class="btn-custom" (click)="removeUsers(master, master?.company_user_id?.user_id?.name)" style="text-align: end;cursor:pointer;">Remove</div>
  <div class="btn-custom" (click)="removeUsers(task, task?.company_user_id?.user_id?.name)">Remove</div>
```

Comment: you need to update the state of the angular app, how are you updating it after the ajax call?

Comment: Do i need to perform some filter function after remove opertion?

Comment: usually yes you do

Comment: I haven't done remove operation .. so please give me some example.. thank you for your quick response..